# Failed to load resource: the server $%7Bthis.originUrl%7D/.auth/me:1 status 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, azure, typescript, visual-studio-code, azure-active-directory

I am new to angular and web development. I am using Visual studio code to develop an angular app and deploy it on azure. I tried to find the solution on all relevant posts to the below mentioned error but was unable to find solution. I am trying to show the logged in user's first name and last name on home page. The user signs in using azure AD B2C. When I run my app I get the following error in browser console

```
Failed to load resource: the server $%7Bthis.originUrl%7D/.auth/me:1 responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I am trying to show user first and last name on web page. file user.services.ts have code like this

```
 export class UserService {
 private originUrl: string;
 private aadUser: AADUser;

      constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('ORIGIN_URL')originUrl: string) {
     this.originUrl = originUrl;
 }
 public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get('${this.originUrl}/.auth/me')
```

home.component.ts is

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
user: User;
ngOnInit(): void {
this.userService.getUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user );
}
```

app.module.ts

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule, 
HttpClientModule,
HttpModule,
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
]),
CommonModule
],
providers: [{provide:'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: 'https://projectname- 
username.azurewebsites.net'}],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It should be backticks ` instead of single quotes in `get('${this.originUrl}/.auth/me')`

Comment: I replaced quotes with backticks ` and now I see the following error in browser console Failed to load [https://projectname-username.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me: Redirect from 'https://projectname-username.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me' to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/azuretkdirectoryusername.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fazurtoolkit-kashifnadeem.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=f4dca851-5057-465d-a9c0-9377978a80a4&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&p=b2c_1_defaultsignuppolicy.... ]

Comment: Sorry, looks like your comment is missing the error, what error are you seeing?

Comment: I edited my comment, did you see the error now?

Comment: I can, and it appears that azure is trying to redirect you to a login page

Comment: you are right, I could't post the complete error in my previous comment. Here is the remaining part after [https://login.microsoft.com/azuredirectoryusername.onmicrosoft.com... ] _ to blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:5001' is therefore not allowed access._

Answer (score 0):

Used following steps to solve the errors,

1. Following error resolved from @user184994 comment

   ```
   Failed to load resource: the server $%7Bthis.originUrl%7D/.auth/me:1 
   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
   ```
2. Second Error

   ```
   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
   present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:5001'; is therefore 
   not allowed access._
   ```

   resolved by adding CROS extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US)

But still I am unable to show user's firstName and lastName on home page.
home.component.html

```
    <script  src="../../Jquery/prettify.js"></script>
    <h1>Hello, {{user?.firstName}} {{user?.lastName}}!</h1>
```

user.services.ts code is

```
    export class UserService {
    private originUrl: string;
    private aadUser: AADUser;

      constructor(private http: Http, @Inject('ORIGIN_URL')originUrl: string) {
     this.originUrl = originUrl;
   }
   public getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.originUrl}/.auth/me`)
        .map(response => {
            try {
                this.aadUser = response.json()[0] as AADUser;

                let user = new User();
                user.userId = this.aadUser.user_id;

                this.aadUser.user_claims.forEach(claim => {
                    switch (claim.typ) {
                        case 
             "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname":
                            user.firstName = claim.val;
                            break;
                        case 
             "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname":
                            user.lastName = claim.val;
                            break;
                    }
                });

                return user;
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                 console.log('Error: ${Exception}');
            }
        }).catch(this.handleError);
       }
       private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
       console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
       return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
      }
      }
```

home.component.ts

```
      @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      })
      export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
      user: User;
      ngOnInit(): void {
      this.userService.getUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user );
      }
```

Comment: How are you setting user in the `home.component.ts` file?

Comment: @user184994, I updated my answer which now includes home.component.ts